# close vscode window via script executed in integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to write a python or bash script such that when I run it from the integrated terminal in vscode it closes the current window?

This may sound useless, so let me explain one use case in case you're wondering why I need to do this, and maybe you also have other suggestions to achieve it. I have a python script that allows me to easily rename a github repo name using github's api: something like `rename-github-repo newname`, which automatically detects the git project directory, makes the changes on github via the api, and renames the directory in my local filesystem as well. After the directory rename, my current vscode window is messed up because it references the old directory, so I'd like to close it and open a new one with the new directory as part of the script `rename-github-repo` so I don't have to do it manually.

Comment: The command for vscode is `code <filename>` so you could add `code <new-repo-name>` to the end of the script which should open it at least.

Comment: yes, I had that part figured out, but closing the current window is the missing part.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to invoke `code` or some related tool to, say, list all the active windows and their current directory names and process IDs. That way I could find the pid of my window and kill the process, that may be one way to do it.

Comment: I tried with `killall -15 code && code <directory> ` and couldn't get it to work. `ps -e | grep code` shows all the vscode pids and there seems to be quite a few with just one instance running.. so maybe there is a way, but I'm not sure.